# Hartley normalization for essential matrix

Tags: matrix, computer-vision

For computing the fundamental matrix using the 8pt algorithm, it is necessary to first normalize the points as laid out in [Hartley's paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjno_Kg9vXJAhXLTCYKHVl1DMwQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fandrew%2Fscs%2Fcs%2F15-463%2Ff07%2Fproj_final%2Fwww%2Famichals%2Ffundamental.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE1xOw9R9UsiSRa4ofb_s_nFemHeA&sig2=WKl_LX8CX0SzNK8Dm612bg). However, if I want to use the 8pt algorithm on calibrated images (i.e. on the essential matrix), do I need to normalize the points on the image plane?

For the fundamental matrix I do the following (in MATLAB-esque pseudocode):

```
% features1 and features2 are (n x 3) matrices of homog. coordinates
[matches1, matches2] = matchFeatures(img1, features1, img2, features2)
[normMatches1, T1] = HartleyNormalization(matches1)
[normMatches2, T2] = HartleyNormalization(matches2)
normF = estimateFundamentalMatrix(normMatches1, normMatches2)
F = T2' * normF * T1;
```

For the essential matrix, can I just do the same thing, but throw an extra first step:

```
features1 = K * features1
features2 = K * features2
```

Where K is my calibration matrix. Or does the Hartley normalization only work for points on the pixel plane?

Comment: PS I know there is a 5pt algorithm for E, but it's nonlinear and thus much more complicated to implement

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to normalize the points for computing the essential matrix. You need to normalize for the fundamental matrix because your points are in pixels, and are typically orders of magnitude greater then the homogeneous w coordinate, which is 1.

On the other hand, when you compute the essential matrix, your points are in the normalized image coordinates, where you move the origin to the principal point, and divide by the focal length in pixels. So your points are effectively normalized already.